# VB.NET WCF Code is throwing 'Attribute Specifier is not a complete statement' error in VS2017

Tags: vb.net, wcf, visual-studio-2017

I need to support some legacy code that is written in VB.NET. This is a WCF solution that is currently working in production. However, when I clone the repo and load it up in VS2017 Build 15.8.5, I am not seeing any syntax issue. No red squiggly lines. But when I rebuild the solution, I get build errors in the Output window but no errors in the Error List.

Here is a section of my Output window.

```
3>Building directory '/App_Code/'.
3>
3>..\ICDI_WCFService.vb(20,0): error BC32035: Attribute specifier is not a complete statement. Use a line continuation to apply the attribute to the following statement.
3>..\ICDI_WCFService.vb(29,0): error BC30604: Statement cannot appear within an interface body. End of interface assumed.
3>..\ICDI_WCFService.vb(30,0): error BC30001: Statement is not valid in a namespace.
3>..\ICDI_WCFService.vb(44,0): error BC30289: Statement cannot appear within a method body. End of method assumed.
```

And here is a sample of the source code that is being referenced in the error messages

```
<ServiceContract()>
Public Interface IIMb
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Used only to expose unused types. 
    ''' <para>WCF does not pass through any classes/enums/etc. that are not explicitly used as either input or ouput of a method</para>
    ''' <para>So, to expose those types, this method was created.</para>
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="imbMailClasses"></param>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    <OperationContract()>
    Sub ExposesUnusedTypes(ByVal imbMailClasses As MAILPiece.IMb.MailClasses)

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Creates IMb PICs for Basic Confirm.
    ''' <para>NOTE: Removes one Address_Only Transaction Count per PIC generated.</para>
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="authHeader"></param>
    ''' <param name="userID"></param>
    ''' <param name="amount"></param>
    ''' <param name="barcodeIdentifier"></param>
    ''' <param name="classAndAddressCorrectionOption"></param>
    ''' <returns>Array [String]</returns>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    <OperationContract()>
    Function CreatePICs_BasicConfirm(ByVal authHeader As AuthHeader, ByVal userID As Integer, ByVal amount As Integer,
                                     ByVal barcodeIdentifier As MAILPiece.IMb.BarcodeIdentifiers,
                                     ByVal classAndAddressCorrectionOption As MAILPiece.IMb.ClassAndAddressCorrectionOptions_Basic_Confirm) As String()
```

It is acting like the  and  are not being used correctly but like I said, this code has been running a long time so I have to wonder if there isn't an issue with VS2017

A coworker cloned the same repo into a VS2017 build 15.4.0 and had the same issue.

It was last worked on in VS2017 this spring, so it has been converted from VS2015 to VS2017 but I have to assume it was a version earlier than VS2017 build 15.4.0

However, I have since installed .NET Core 2.x SDKs on my DEV laptop.

Before I go through the pain of setting up a clean laptop with VS2017 Build 15.0 I wanted to see if anyone has experienced this issue.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE 1**

This legacy solution uses a VB website project for the WCF service (wrapper?) and does not have a vbproj file.

There are other projects in the solution that are referenced by this web site project that do have vbproj files (and they do not have a LangVersion setting) but this one does not. However, I can right-click on the project name and select "Edit Project Item Properties" and I can see that VB Language Level is set to Default. I tried setting it to Visual Basic .NET 15 and it made no difference in the errors.

If I try to add an underscore (for line continuation) after the  attribute, is disappears as soon as I move off the line.

[image: Screenshot of project right-click menu]

**Update 2**

The highlighted CDI_WCFService3 item in the Solution Explorer image above looks like it should be a project that has vbproj file but there is no vbproj file in the actual folder. There is a web.config file and in that web.config file is the section shown below;

That is the only thing that even mentions VB.

Here is a screenshot of the folder structure.

[image: project folder]

Comment: "I can see that VB Language Level is set to Default" - Unlike VS/C#, VS/VB does not provide a means to change the language level; it must be done via modify the vbproj (MSBuild) file. Your image appears to show the [Configuring Project-Specific Properties Dialog](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Configuring_Project_Specific_Properties.html) from Resharper. Their description implies that that setting only affects their code inspection tooling. I suggest that you righ-click unload that project then right-click edit CDI_WCFService and re-inspect the project file for the LangVersion tag.

Comment: It could be possible that MSBuild is pullying that setting from higher up the chain (Microsoft.Common.props), but that means you have other issues on the system.  If the system is fu-barred, it could also be possible that the wrong compiler is being used (assuming it exists on the machine).  Try launching a command prompt from VS and entering `vbc -langversion:?`.  That command will only work on the most recent compilers.

Comment: "If I try to add an underscore (for line continuation) after the attribute, is disappears as soon as I move off the line." - That is due to _pretty listing_. You can disable it via Tools Menu->Options->Text Editor-> Basic->Advanced->Editor Help->Pretty listing.  Alternatively, do an undo (cntrl-Z) to bring it back with pretty listing enabled, but that is a pain.

Comment: TnTinMn - See update 2 above

Answer (score 0):

The errors look like the build is using the compiler from VS 2008 that did not support implicit line continuations.  Or at least the current compiler with the [langversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/reference/command-line-compiler/langversion) compiler option set.  The referenced documentation states that this is command-line only option, but including the following in the MSBuild file (ProjectName.vbproj) will reproduce your issue in VS 2017:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <LangVersion>9.0</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

So check the vbproj file to see if the above somehow got added to the file.  Also, if you have "Directory.Build.props" file (see: [Customize your build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2017)),  check in that file as well.